# How can I access a flash drive without having to be root?

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, nixos

I was wondering how I could access a flash drive without having to be root?

I am accessing it on NixOS below (and will have to access it on a printer, which may have the permission problem).

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  32.5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0    60G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0 838.5G  0 part /home
└─sda4   8:4    0   511M  0 part /boot
sdb      8:16   1  28.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  28.9G  0 part 
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ~/media/flashdrive/

$ cp helloworld ~/media/flashdrive/
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/t/media/flashdrive/helloworld': Permission denied
$ sudo cp helloworld ~/media/flashdrive/
$ cd ~/media/flashdrive/
$ mkdir 2022
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘2022’: Permission denied
$ sudo mkdir 2022

$ cd ..
$ ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  16384 Dec 31  1969 flashdrive
$ sudo umount  ~/media/flashdrive/
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 t users 4096 Nov 24 01:37 flashdrive
```

Following the latest comment, checking the mounting point without being mounted any device to:

```
$ cd  ~/media/flashdrive/
$ ~/program_files/OS/files/permissions/pathlld.sh  .
drwxr-xr-x 2 t users 4096 Nov 24 01:37 .
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered `pmount`?

Comment: Can I not to  ... ?

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: Mount it in userspace via D-BUS: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1` This will mount the partition at `/run/media/$USER/$LABEL` where `$LABEL` is either the disk label or the partition UUID if no label exists.